# AjaxRequestTarget doesn't exist in Button.onSubmit()

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, wicket

AjaxRequestTarget given from RequestCycle is obviously null when I try to get in method Button.onSubmit().

I want to open a popup window using Ajax, but it throws ever NullPointerException. Is there a way to show a popup using AjaxRequestTarget in the onsubmit() function in Wicket?

```
  protected void onSubmit() {
       if (trainingmode()){
          AjaxRequestTarget target =  RequestCycle.get().find(AjaxRequestTarget.class);

          MessageDialog dialog = new MessageDialog("dialog", "Notice", "Decision Matches "  ,
             DialogButtons.OK_CANCEL, DialogIcon.WARN) {

         public void onClose(  AjaxRequestTarget target, DialogButton button) {

         }
     };
     System.out.println("2Chainz");
     dialog.open(target);
          }
```

}

I get an error at dialog.open(target) that says :
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.googlecode.wicket.jquery.ui.widget.dialog.MessageDialog.onOpen(MessageDialog.java:170)
    at com.googlecode.wicket.jquery.ui.widget.dialog.AbstractDialog.open(A

I am trying to have an AjaxRequestTarget modal window pop up appear however i do not have access to AjaxRequestTarget from within the onsubmit()

Comment: Your question is a bit poor, please provide more details. Do you mean open a diaglog (e.g. 'Confirm Save' on a form) or do you mean the Wicket modal window, that requires AjaxRequestTarget that is not available in onSubmti() function on a form or SubmitLink?

Comment: @MartinStrejc I mean the later using modal window despite ajaxrequesttarget not being available.

Comment: Please, let me know the class you are extending, it is not obvious, because onSubmit() is at classes Button and Form, the solution is different.

Answer (score 1):

NullPointerException is thrown because of using *wrong* component.

Use the [AjaxButton](http://ci.apache.org/projects/wicket/apidocs/6.x/org/apache/wicket/ajax/markup/html/form/AjaxButton.html) or [AjaxSubmitLink](http://ci.apache.org/projects/wicket/apidocs/6.x/org/apache/wicket/ajax/markup/html/form/AjaxSubmitLink.html) instead of [Button](http://ci.apache.org/projects/wicket/apidocs/6.x/org/apache/wicket/markup/html/form/Button.html) and implement method onSubmit(AjaxRequestTarget) instead of method onSubmit().

**Explanation:**

[AjaxRequestTarget](http://ci.apache.org/projects/wicket/apidocs/6.x/org/apache/wicket/ajax/AjaxRequestTarget.html) is available ONLY if an AJAX requested is invoked. [RequestCycle](http://ci.apache.org/projects/wicket/apidocs/6.x/org/apache/wicket/request/cycle/RequestCycle.html) is a thread local singleton that contains AjaxRequestTarget object only in the case of AJAX request, otherwise the method you're using reaturns null because it doesn't find any AjaxRequestTarget object.

Answer (score 0):

In-order to get an `AjaxRequestTarget`, you ll need `AjaxButton` or `AjaxLink`, `AjaxSubmitLink` etc.

These components have methods like `onClick(AjaxRequestTarget target)` or `onSubmit(AjaxRequestTarget target)`, you can use these.

In case you are dealing with input fields, you can add `AjaxFormCompanentUpadingBehaviour`, which ll get you an `AjaxRequestTarget`.